# «Общаюсь как получается» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая в таком выражении: *общаюсь как получается*?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что вы спутали "как получается" с наречными выражениями, которые не требуют постановки знаков препинания (*где попало, как попало, где придется, как придется, **как получится***...).

[**как придётся**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172833/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA), *нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.*

1. **Как получится** (*обычно в зависимости от каких-либо обстоятельств, условий, возможностей*). Употребляется как несогласованное определение.
2. Беспорядочно, бессистемно.
   Употребляется как несогласованное определение.

Я не стал лечиться, продолжал пьянствовать, в морозы ходил полураздетым, без головного убора. **Спал где придется и как придется.** [Александр Зиновьев. Русская судьба, исповедь отщепенца (1988-1998)]

> ― Ум у тебя не аналитический, ― сказала мне Надежда Васильевна. ― **Ты живешь как получится.**
> ― Быстро вы меня изучили, ― сказал я.
> (Владимир Железников. Жизнь и приключения чудака)

*Общаюсь, как получается* (как удается общаться, как выходит) — запятая перед "как" необходима. *Общаюсь как получится* (беспорядочно, хаотично, как попало, как придется, урывками) — запятая не нужна.

Дайте вы мне **жить, как получается,** а? [Александр Кабаков. Последний герой (1994-1995)]

Она была уверена, что, сколько ни рассуждай на эту тему, толку никакого не будет. Надо просто **жить, как получается**... [Татьяна Тронина. Русалка для интимных встреч (2004)]

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна.

Здесь придаточное предложение, так как в сравнительном обороте есть глагол:
*ОбщАюсь, как (у меня) получАется.*

Сравнить:
*Общаюсь как оратор.*